# How does autoresizing mask work?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, autoresizingmask

I've found a lot of information on autoresizing but none has been able to solve my problem.  I have a ViewController (RAViewController) who calls a view in its loadView method like so:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    // Set Navigation Bar Title
    self.navigationItem.title = @"RA";

    // Add Background view
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Add RAView
    RAView *rAView = [[RAView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame Controller:self];
    [self.view rAView];
}
```

The view it calls (RAView) looks like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame Controller:(RAViewController *)Controller
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        self.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];

        controller = Controller;

        // Draw Architecture View
        [self drawArchitectureView];
    }
return self;
}

-(void)drawArchitectureView {
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, self.frame.size.width - 20, 50);

    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [button setTitle:@"Overview" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self addSubview:button];
}
```

For some reason I can't get autoresizing mask to resize the button width when the device is landscape.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you'll need to set the autoresizingMask on the UIButton itself.

Comment: Tried that.  The button ended up being moved off the screen, which is not what I expected which means I don't really understand how it works.  Also isn't the point of `self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;` so I don't have to do that?

Comment: What did you try setting the buttons autoresizeMask to? Did you try UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin ?

Comment: Also, the autoresizesSubviews property is YES by defaul, so there's no need to set it like you are. This allows the autoresizingMask property of the subview to work. If it was no, there would be no resizing.

Comment: Alright good because I took that out.  Yes, it centers the button but does not make it as long as I want.  For some reason the height and width values are not swapping.

Comment: What's this line for: [button setFrame:frame] ? What is 'frame' here?

Comment: sorry about that.  It was left over from an earlier attempt.

Comment: Ok I see you deleted it now, did that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to keep the same height, but just stay fully centered, 10.0 from the left and right, try:

```
-(void)drawArchitectureView {
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, self.frame.size.width - 20, 50);

    button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [button setTitle:@"Overview" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self addSubview:button];
}
```