# Scale UIImageView after orientation changed

Tags: ios, cocoa, uiview, uiimageview, contentmode

In my application i have UIIMageView within UIView, in portrait mode imageview fills whole area of UIView, but after orientation is changed UIView rotates but not stretched, though i have set content mode of UIView to Scale to fill, what is wrong?

Comment: screens would helped in this situation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the autoresizing mask:

```
yourUIImageViewInstance.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

read also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388508/how-does-autoresizing-mask-work).

Comment: thanks it helps me, but in this case i don't understand the meaning of content mode of view, as i know when we set content mode to Stretch to fill the child controls should be stretched to fill whole area right ?

Comment: content mode "Stretch" means the UIImage gets stretches into the UIImageView BUT NOT the UIImageView in the superview! For that you need autoresizing.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using

```
 imageview.frame=CGMakeRect(x, y, width, height);
```

in setPositionForOrientation function